# How to use FutureBuilder to build ListTile using List data

Tags: list, build, dart, flutter

List> _userAccounts;

**Result:**

```
_CurrentUserAccounts: [
    [Current Account, 10.06, United States Dollar USD], 
    [Demand Deposit, 55.22, British Pound GBP], 
    [Current Account, 250, Euro EUR], 
    [Deposit Account, 0, Euro EUR]
]
```

**Format:**
[AccountName, CurrentBalance, CurrencyName],

I need to use this info (List>) to build a ListTile.
This is for only one user. Some user might 1 account and some of them might have over 10 accounts.

What is the best practice to show this data? I am planing to use ListTile so, if user tabs the ListTile so they can get details of the
certain account.

So, How to use FutureBuilder to build ListTile using List data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an instance of **FutureBuilder** to home or root widget. As you can see below.

```
body: new FutureBuilder<List<Country>>(
        future: fetchCountry(new http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? new CountyList(country: snapshot.data)
              : new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
```

I have found a simple example for it [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/06/flutter-display-list-of-country-by.html).